Is preposition difficult to understand even for young native speaker?
Is preposition difficult to understand even for young native speaker ? I have this question because it is difficult for many Chinese (me included).
Then I am reading "Making Sense. The Glamorous Story Of English Grammar" by David Crystal and I am amused by this story,

On that day in the early 1970s, I was halfway through my usual
explanation when I noticed that my audience had begun to fidget (more
than usual). Some were whispering to each other. I stopped what I was
saying and asked: ‘Is there a problem?’
One student put her hand up. ‘Please,’ she said, ‘What’s a
preposition?’
I was, as I used to say in Liverpool, gobsmacked. I had never been
asked that question before. It had never occurred to me that someone,
now aged 18, could have gone through school without learning what a
preposition was. I asked the audience: ‘How many of you don’t know
what a preposition is?’ Most put their hands up. I couldn’t believe
it.
‘I think I know,’ said another student. ‘Thank goodness,’ I thought,
and asked her to continue. Then she said: ‘Is it something to do with
getting on a horse?’


This is nothing to do with using prepositions.
The point of this story is that teaching of grammar in English schools was almost non-existent in the 1970s, as the emphasis was on encouraging students to express themselves. As the narrator states, university students who had come out of those schools would mostly not know what a preposition even is, let alone how to identify one in a sentence.
It really wasn't until the 90s that grammar really came back onto the syllabus in schools. And as someone who was at school in the 70s and 80s, the only time I learned any grammar at all was in French and German lessons - it wasn't covered at all in English.

I didn't know that!!

This is very accurate for me too (started school aged 5 in 1957). The sum total of grammar up to age 11 was that verbs were 'doing words', nouns were 'names of things', and adjectives 'told you something about nouns'. The rest was just picked up as you went along. Any ideas about grammar or structure we got after age 11 from French (and in my case) Latin. By the way, most native speakers, even educated ones, will have absolutely no idea what 'first, second, or third conditionals' are.

I remember being astonished, some thirty years ago, when a young colleague asked "What's an adjective?"

But why was that?

Why was I astonished? For the same reason that David Crystal was - I couldn't believe that an intelligent young woman didn't know what an adjective was.

@KateBunting I know the part why you were astonished, I meant why that happened. Why your colleague did not know what adjective was.

Presumably for the reason Daniel gives; that children weren't taught formal grammar in the 1970s when she would have been at school.

Thanks for the great answer but a follow-up question is why grammar teaching was almost non-existent in 70s and why it came back 90s. And what is the situation now ?

Daniel Roseman's answer does a good job explaining what happened in the quote you gave. But to more directly address the question you have, prepositions are widely considered (among) the most difficult to teach.
Children learn to use them without being taught, of course—the only reliable way to learn them is through continued exposure. But identifying them in a sentence and explaining what they do is significantly more abstract than for nouns, verbs, adjectives, or adverbs. Again this is mostly done by example, pointing out prepositions within familiar phrases and sentences. I remember being taught around age 10, but others' experiences may vary.

With your answer and Daniel Roseman's, I rethink about the grammar teaching. From my experience  the grammar teaching is over-emphasized. But on the other hand continued exposure to English is hard for us.
